# Node js event loop: Safe for-looping and Python difference

Tags: node.js, express, event-loop

While working on a project for my Express app, I wrote a recursive method that retrieves data from some nested JSON object. Roughly, the method looks like:

```
# The depth of the fields is up to 3-4 levels, so no stack overflow danger.

  _recursiveFindFieldName: function(someJSONStruct, nestedFieldList) {

if (nestedFieldList.length === 0) {
  return someJSONStruct;
}

fields = someJSONStruct['fields'];
for (var i=0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  subField = fields[i];
  if (subField['fieldName'] === nestedFieldList[0]) {
    return this._recursiveFindFieldName(subField, nestedFieldList.splice(1));
  }
}
return null;
```

Now, I call this method one my callbacks, by stating
`data = _recursiveFindFieldName(someJSON, fieldPathList);`. However, a friend who reviewed my code noted that this method, being recursive and iterative over potentially large JSON struct, may block the event loop and prevent Express from serving other requests.

While it does make sense, I am not sure if I should be ever concerned about CPU-synchronous tasks (as opposed to I/O). At least intuitively it does not look very simple.

I have tried to use this [source](https://www.rdegges.com/2014/for-loops-in-node/) to understand better how the event loop works, and was really surprised to see that the following code crashes my local node REPL.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  console.log('hi:', i);
}
```

What I am not sure is why it happens, as opposed to Python (that runs single-thread as well, and easily handles the task of printing), and whether it's relevant to my case, which does not involve I/O operations.

Comment: I think this might be good reading: [Don't Block the Event Loop (or the Worker Pool)](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/).

Comment: Yes, I have read it before (might be good idea to re-read it, actually) and tested potential DDOS. The thing is they all mention "Blocking event loop" in the context of disk I/O and Network I/O, whereas my method doesn't use any. Therefore, I am not sure if I'm actually **blocking** it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **measure** the performance of your existing code: it probably isn't a bottleneck to begin with.

If the supposed bottleneck is actually valid, you can create an asynchronous [Node C++ add-on](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), which can process the entire JSON blob via `uv_queue_work()` in a separate thread, outside of the JavaScript event loop, and then return the entire result via  back to JavaScript, using a promise.

Is this supported performance bottleneck big enough of a concern to warrant this?  Probably not.

As for your console.log() question: in Node, sometimes stdio is synchronous, and sometimes it's not: see [this discussion](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/api/process.md#a-note-on-process-io).  If you are on a POSIX system, it's synchronous, and you are writing enough data to fill up the pipe and block the event loop, which is all getting jammed in there before the next event tick.  I'm not sure of the specifics on why that causes a crash, but hopefully this is a start to answering your question.